# Regular DVDs won't play

Tags: video-player

I have the plugins which I need but it doesn't play after all. My DVDs are new and I tried more than one and none of them work. I can play self-created DVDs with no problems.

I tried different players like Dragon, VLC, SMPlayer; the ones everyone says are good. I don't doubt it and SMPlayer is good but, you know, no DVDs!

If I try Dragon it displays all black. If I try VLC it jumps from one data to another but it doesn't play. If I try SMPlayer it shows me that it was played... but it didn't play at all.

Comment: Well for that totem thing I only get Arte-addition for totem, hope translated it right. So it's sorta different.

Comment: How about your codecs? Is your DVD ROM working properly?

Comment: you mean my drive? yes no problem. What codecs you mean? I can say to 100% it`s not the dvd.

Comment: The question linked above is quite old; VLC, for example, now handles DVD menus very well. It sounds as though you don't have `libdvdread4` (and thus `libdvdcss2`) installed correctly. Try repeating the instructions for installing them. Or maybe it is a region code problem? The community docs for playing DVDs are here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Answer (score -2):

Solution 1:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Solution 2:

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list `http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list`
sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring
sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

*Then update Synaptic:

```
sudo update-apt-xapian-index
```

*Install codec for your Ubuntu 32 or 64 bit:

```
sudo apt-get -y install w32codecs ubuntu-restricted-extras    (32bit)
sudo apt-get -y install w64codecs ubuntu-restricted-extras    (64bit)
```

*Enable full-DVD support:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Comment: Medibuntu repositories are dead.

Comment: I forgot about that... Then he should try installing just codec pack for his version of Ubuntu and enable Full-DVD support. If his hardware is working properly it should work. I just can't think of what else it could be...

Comment: Solution one ... I have it. where does I enter Solution 2?

Comment: I have all these... enable full dvd support, how do I do that?